# ngx_stream_core_module and end user ip

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, tcp

Let's say I have some service working on a raw TCP level and I want to add a load balancing to it. I've tried to use `ngx_stream_core_module`. While TCP-streams are indeed proxied to backend servers, I found some issues I'm not able to resolve.

1. My service wrote in node.js and it's a common technique to set up processes manager, like pm2, which restarts the node in case it consumed too much memory. But this obviously will terminate all connected clients. My expectation was nginx will connect users to next server in upstream (well, maybe it's too > 2016, but), but my connection just closes.
2. My service requires end user ip and remote port to operate, but in application socket's remoteAddress and remotePort are points to local nginx instance. I.e. when I print it to buffer, I see 127.0.0.1 when connection is proxied and my real ip when I connect to the node directly. I see that nginx support some config variables (since v.1.11.2), and $remote_addr is among them. But I don't see any information how to forward this variable to upstream. `proxy_set_header` directive is unavailable inside stream and it looks ok since there is no any "headers" in TCP. Is this even possible?
3. I'm not a devops, but a coder, so I heard about haproxy, but I have no clue if it can resolve this two issues. Can it?

For testing I used dumb echo node.js server, where all the working part is narrowed to

```
server.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.write(`Hello from ${instance}, ${socket.remoteAddress}:${socket.remotePort}\n`);
});
```

And the related part of my nginx config is

```
stream {
    upstream echo {
        server localhost:9000;
        server localhost:9001;
    }

    server {
        listen 8080;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1s;
        proxy_timeout 2h;
        proxy_pass echo;
    }
}
```

Finally I used netcat to check things.

```
// direct connect
~|⇒  nc 95.85.15.120 9000
Hello, ::ffff:86.110.174.98:65408

// proxied connect
~|⇒  nc 95.85.15.120 8080
Hello, ::ffff:127.0.0.1:44056
```

Here is the [module docs](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. That's not something that could work with TCP, because it certainly will break almost any protocol that works ontop. For example, what if a connection will be dropped in the middle of some message or command?
2. You can use [the proxy protocol](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_proxy_module.html#proxy_protocol) to transfer original IPs, but it need to be supported by your backend.

   Or you can configure [binding to clients IPs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_proxy_module.html#proxy_bind):

   ```
    proxy_bind $remote_addr transparent;
   ```

Comment: Well, you have a strong point about #1. Looks like we will need to rise memory limits and pray for good. Transparent binding fails on my nginx, but it was from stable branch, while this option was introduced in 1.11.0. I'll recompile my nginx to ensure it works, but it looks promising. Thank you. I never realized that directives of `ngx_stream_proxy_module` works for stream core module too.

Comment: @Tommi, you DO use proxy_module (directive `proxy_pass`) and `proxy_bind` affects that directive.

Comment: Ok, I supposed that proxy stream core module is something separated from generic proxy module. Docs are quite unclear. I checking proxy_bind directive right now. I will accept your answer as soon as I finish my experiments.

Comment: Still can't get it work. I set `user root;` in conf because I've got an error about denied permission to use transparent socket binding, but now upstreams just timed out, like `*1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: 86.110.174.98, server: 0.0.0.0:8197, upstream: "127.0.0.1:9001", bytes from/to client:0/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0`. Maybe it's because of magical "configure kernel routing table to intercept network traffic from the proxied server" part of manual. Maybe I should google it or create another question. Thank you again.

Comment: _In order for this parameter to work, it is necessary to run nginx worker processes with the superuser privileges **and configure kernel routing table** to intercept network traffic from the proxied server_

Comment: @Tommi yes, you have to configure your routing, see for more details: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tproxy.txt